# How to calculate mean curvature of axisymmetric deformed surface?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, axisymmetry

I tried to calculate mean curvature of laser induced axisymmetric deformed surface, which radial dependence of height is given by:

```
γw = 70.0*10^-3; (*SR in N/m*)
ρ = 1000;
c = 3*10^8;
g = 9.8;
size = 600;
u1 = γw*k^2 + ρ*g;
we1 = 7*10^-6; (*beam waist*)
n = 1.33;
P0 = 4.0;
rng = 120*10^-6; P1 = (P0/(c*Pi))*((n - 1)/(n + 1));

f70[r_] := P1*Exp[-(we1^2*k^2)/8]*k*BesselJ[0, r*k]/u1
h70[r_?NumericQ] := 
 Quiet[NIntegrate[f70[r], {k, 0, ∞}, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}, MinRecursion -> 4, 
   MaxRecursion -> 100]]

hp70 = Plot[10^9*(h70[r]), {r, -rng, rng}, Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.006]}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> size, LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, 18], Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit in your question? What does the plot represent? Do you have a definition of the quantity you are trying to calculate? What is the relationship between the variables you introduced and that quantity?

Comment: Thanks @Marcob, plot represent the height as function of radial coordinate. I want to calculate principal curvatures so that I can calculate the mean curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean curvature in a case of axial symmetric surface `h[y]` can be defined in a form

```
H[y_] := (h''[y]/(1 + h'[y]^2)^(3/2) + h'[y]/Sqrt[1 + h'[y]^2]/y)/2;
```

Using numeric integral we can compute interpolation function described surface `h` as follows

```
\[Gamma]w = 70.0*10^-3;(*SR in N/m*)\[Rho] = 1000;
c = 3*10^8;
g = 9.8;
size = 600;
u1 = \[Gamma]w*k^2 + \[Rho]*g;
we1 = 7*10^-6;(*beam waist*)n = 1.33;
P0 = 4.0;
rng = 120*10^-6; P1 = (P0/(c*Pi))*((n - 1)/(n + 1));

f70[r_] := P1*Exp[-(we1^2*k^2)/8]*k*BesselJ[0, r*k]/u1
h70[r_?NumericQ] := 
 Quiet[NIntegrate[f70[r], {k, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}, MinRecursion -> 4, 
   MaxRecursion -> 100]]
lst = Table[{r, h70[r]}, {r, 10^-6, rng, 10^-6}];

h = Interpolation[lst, InterpolationOrder -> 4];
```

At `r->0` function `H[r]` has singularity, therefore we need to regularize `h` by using series

```
f7 = Series[BesselJ[0, r*k], {r, 0, 7}] // Normal

(*Out[]= 1 - (k^2 r^2)/4 + (k^4 r^4)/64 - (k^6 r^6)/2304*)

 h7 = 
 Integrate[P1*Exp[-(we1^2*k^2)/8]*k*f7/u1, {k, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> r > 0]

(*Out[]= 5.74997*10^-8 - 175.246 r^2 + 1.78824*10^12 r^4 - 
 1.62199*10^22 r^6 *)
```

Finally we define `H7` and point `r=rmin` to join `H7` and `H`

```
H7 = (D[h7, {r, 2}]/(1 + D[h7, r]^2)^(3/2) + 
    D[h7, r]/Sqrt[1 + D[h7, r]]/r)/2

 rmin = 
 r /. FindMinimum[Abs[H7 - H[r]], {r, 2 10^-6, 10^-6, 10^-5}][[2]] // 
  Quiet

(*Out[]= 1.79474*10^-6 *)
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[If[r < rmin , H7, H[r]], {r, 0, 10^-5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 200], 
 Plot[If[r < rmin, H7, H[r]], {r, 0, rng}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 200]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Thanks@Alex, It is working.  Please also suggest that Can I straight forward calculate the mean curvature derivative? What about the small slope limit approximation?

Comment: @GopalVerma It could be better to use piecewise function  `If[r < rmin , H7, H[r]]` for approximation mean curvature only. For derivative we need some smooth differentiable  function based on it. For instance, we can prepare new function as follows `Hnew = Interpolation[
  Table[{r, If[r < rmin, H7, H[r]]}, {r, 0, rng, rng/1000}], 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3]`

Comment: Thanks@Alex, It is working.

Comment: This code Hnew = Interpolation[   Table[{r, If[r < rmin, H7, H[r]]}, {r, 0, rng, rng/1000}],    InterpolationOrder -> 3] showing 1/0 expression, but if I replaced 0 with small number e.g. 10^-7,then we can calculate derivative and plot it, but plotted graph is not smooth and does not have negative values (it should have in some region). Please suggest full code regarding derivative.

Comment: @GopalVerma To avoid singularity 1/0 we can use `H7 = (D[h7, {r, 2}]/(1 + D[h7, r]^2)^(3/2) + 
     D[h7, r]/Sqrt[1 + D[h7, r]]/r)/2 // FullSimplify`

Comment: if mean curvature H[y_] := (h''[y]/(1 + h'[y]^2)^(3/2) + h'[y]/Sqrt[1 + h'[y]^2]/y)/2; has -ve sign then I found a different type of curve. Pls, suggest if we need to change something.

Comment: @GopalVerma I don't understand your question. Could you explain what do you need to change?

Comment: Our main concern is how to determine the sign of mean curvature H[y].

Comment: It depends on `h[y]`. For example, in the plot above sign is negative.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Of course, it depends upon h[y] but generally dimple-type surface has negative curvature but h(y) profile has a bump that should have +ve curvature. Have a look in the article at Fig. 5 (Characterization of a fracture zone using seismic attributes at the In Salah CO2 storage project)

Comment: or  in this link https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Curvature

Comment: We can't say something in general. If you have practical example, please, post it.